# How can I catch SIGNAL(subWindowActivated(QMdiSubWindow*)) when it is NULL?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the main menu to delete some items when the QMdiArea is empty, so I tried to use:

```
connect(mdiArea, SIGNAL(subWindowActivated(QMdiSubWindow*)), this, SLOT(on_mdiArea_changed()));
```

to catch the signal, but I found that it cannot catch a null signal, so how can I solve this problem? THX

Comment: use new syntax: `connect(mdiArea, &QMdiArea::subWindowActivated, this &YourClass::on_mdiArea_changed);`

Comment: OK I'll change it, thx. I'm a green hand so I fail to notice such problem of syntax...But I still don't know how to get the signal when there're no window in QMdiArea...

Comment: The subWindowActivated signal is emited when a QMdiSubWindow is activated, but if the QMdiArea does not have any QMdiSubWindow then the signal will never be emited.

Comment: OK, I'll stop using this signal, thx.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using Qt4.

Header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
class QMdiArea;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QMdiArea *mdiArea{};
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMdiArea>
#include <QMdiSubWindow>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    mdiArea = new QMdiArea;
    setCentralWidget(mdiArea);
    auto w = new QMdiSubWindow;

    connect(w,&QMdiSubWindow::windowStateChanged,[=](){
        if(w->windowState() == Qt::WindowNoState){
            mdiArea->removeSubWindow(w);
            if(mdiArea->subWindowList().size() == 0){
                qDebug() << "modify the menu";
            }
        }
    });
    mdiArea->addSubWindow(w);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested ?, IMHO that code does not compile since the signature between the signal and slot does not match.

Comment: Sorry but it cannot solve my problem. I think it's my fault not to describe what I need clearly. The function I need is that after I press the button "X" in the upper right corner of the last window and close it, I can know that there is no subwindow in mdiArea so I can change the menu. However, I tried to create a subwindow in your way, and after I closed the last window, it seemed that subWindowList()->size() was always 1. Maybe after I close the window it cannot send messages to me? Anyway, thx so much.

Comment: @JYF Do you call the remove method? It's working fine in Qt4.

Comment: @张铁男 To be honest I am using QT5. And I tried to call removeSubWindow(s), however, actually when I use other methods to create a new subwindow, the state of the old window will also change, then it closes. So I annotate that line. In my opinion maybe windowStateChanged happens before it is closed by the "X" button, so at that time it still exists.

Comment: @JYF I will use Qt5 to do this.

Comment: @张铁男 Thx very much!

Comment: @JYF In Qt5, sender() does not work. I don't know why, but I lambda is a better choice.

Comment: @JYF Its a prototype, you have to add code like maintaining the subwindows, to identify which subwindow is closed. Then you will get the correct pointer of the subwindow to remove.